# Ethereum sendtransaciton(EIP-155)

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm Beginner of Ethereum and now test the transaction in My testnet
when I testing the sendtransaction below
`eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to:eth.accounts[1], value:web3.toWei(10), chainId: 0})`

Return error like this "Error: only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC"

How can I modify it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzBVT.png)

Comment: seems like your chainId is not valid

Comment: try chainid 1337

Answer (score 0):

EIP-155 introduced to include the chainId inside the transaction to avoid replays of the transaction on different chain, check which chainId corresponds to the network you are using and update the chainId value accordingly.